# Both time `rsync` and get its exit value?

Tags: rsync, time

If I want to time the running of `rsync` by `time rsync -a /media/t/1/  ./`, after it finishes, does `$?` report the exit value for `time` not for `rsync`?

How can I both time `rsync` and get its exit value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash's built-in time returns the exit status of the command. You can test that fairly easily with `time false`; afterwards, `echo $?` prints 1 as expected. You can also test something with a different exit code to confirm other codes are preserved:

```
$ time bash -c 'exit 42'; echo "Exit code: $?"

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
Exit code: 42
```